# Thriller movie: young policeman with motorbike vs. farmer serial killer

Tags: identify-this-movie, thriller

I'm looking for a movie I saw as a child over 30 years ago and I was barely paying attention.

The story was centered around disappearances of a number people over years, perhaps decades. It was set in a small town. The kind of place where it would be otherwise be great to raise a family and live the quiet life except of course there is a serial killer near. The killer lived on the outskirts of the same locality. I remember there were 4 perhaps 5 chapters to this story and each of them was a different era of the killer doing his nasty deeds.

I distinctly remember one of his victims being a young police officer. The officer rode a police motorbike. At some point the young officer figured out that the "farmer Joe" type serial killer was in fact **A KILLER**. I think the officer was visiting the killers' farm when he came across one of many burial sites the killer used to dispose of his victims. Unfortunately, the officer, and his cool motorbike, ended up in one such grave on the same property.

Finally, somehow the burial sites were discovered. There were A LOT of burial sites. What I don't remember is if the killer died a ripe old man or was arrested and jailed as a ripe old man.

Comment: Please don't use tags if you're not sure what they're for. I know that those tags don't have wikis but if you'd looked at them, you'd see that they're for specific film titles.

Comment: @Catija: Sure but not much I could do without relevant tags to choose from

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Chiefs](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0084997/), a miniseries from 1983.

> This series tells the story of **a southern town's police chiefs** and the
>   **serial murderer** who confounds them. Will Henry Lee is the first chief,
>   an easygoing man who works to establish the position while the
>   murderer begins his havoc. The second is a violent racist who stumbles
>   about his job as the murderer continues his. Tyler Watts is the final
>   chief in the story, an African-American cop who must deal with the
>   virulent racism of his community while he puts together the pieces to
>   finally bring the murderer to justice.

The police chief with the motorbike was Sonny Butts, the violent racist.  The serial killer was played by Keith Carradine.  The final chief is played by Billy Dee Williams.

Comment: Thank you Will. That's exactly what I've been looking for. Very surprised to see the cast included the late great Mr Heston

Answer (score 0):

The miniseries was called "Chiefs" and can be found on imdb as far as additional information. The burial site was behind the serial killer's house and in one of the 'graves' was Chief Sonny Butts, replete with his motorcycle. It was a really good drama. I myself was just now looking for it's name after telling a friend about it. It's been so long that I didn't remember much about it except it was really, really well done.

Comment: Welcome to the community. Why not put some links into your answer to make more reader friendly?